# NServiceBus and WCF

Tags: wcf, nservicebus

I want to achieve the following:

1. Expose WCF endpoint to client from which they request a long-running operation.
2. Map the inbound request to a NServiceBus Message.
3. Publish the message to the bus for processing.
4. Send a reply to the client acking that their request has been received and we will begin processing it.
5. Bus works the message through a handler.

Can you help me with some examples here please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's wrong with the samples that NServiceBus provides [in the official documentation](http://support.nservicebus.com/)? You can also download NServiceBus from there, code samples are included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out the WcfIntegration sample that comes with NSB to see how to expose an endpoint via WCF.  To hand off the message, you can simply call Bus.Send() to another endpoint to do processing, then use the Bus.Return() that is in the sample.  From there, the other endpoint can look just like the Server part of the FullDuplex sample without the Bus.Reply() logic.

Comment: Am unable to find this sample or am I looking at the wrong location. This is what I am referring to. http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/topics/404708-samples/articles?page=1

Comment: Yea, its not out there, it should be in the download.

Answer (score 1):

Awhile ago I created some example code that is similar to this, although it used a traditional ASMX web service and not a WCF one, but that is really just an implementation detail.

Check out [NServiceBus External WebService Example](https://github.com/DuctTapeMan/NServiceBus-External-WebService-Example) on GitHub.